# Allow prepopulating the tags field when linking to the Ask Question page

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, hyperlinks, asking-questions, tags

On Gaming, we would like to use game-specific and genre-specific tags. As such, it would be helpful to have links to the Ask question page which have the tag field prepopulated.

For example, one could post the following link on the Braid forums:

```
https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/ask?tags=braid+puzzle+pc
```

Comment: Not sure how often this would be used, but +1 for an innovative idea!

Comment: Oh damn, I wrote like a whole page of a question before seeing this one.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

OK, good idea, this is complete.

You can specify default title and tags parameters to the `/ask` page like so:

`http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/ask?title=foo&tags=tag1+tag2+tag3`

Comment: You can also use a comma instead of a `+` for tags.