# Shouldn't meta.stackoverflow.com be on the Stack Exchange list?

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, stackexchange-2.0, meta, stack-exchange

I can understand per-site metas not being on the list at https://stackexchange.com/sites, but this site is the central discussion site for the engine itself.  Its reputation system is even segregated from Stack Overflow.

That, and I want to be able to compare its stats with the other sites at a glance.

Comment: Amazing how Gaming has already surpassed Meta for views per day.  Thanks @Jeff.

Answer (score 2):

[image: Just link to it from the StackExchange dropdown.]

This mockup relies on my previous proposal on [question URLs with a prepopulated tag field](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/57594/allow-prepopulating-the-tags-field-when-linking-to-the-ask-question-page). (Alternatively, it's just one link pointing to MSO.)

Answer (score 0):

Every Stack Exchange site has it's own meta, the site list would be bloated if all meta sites were there.

However, there could be separate list for meta sites. The meta sites are usually only for users of the parent sites, so I understand that they don't want to present them on the web, because it may not be interesting for other people (that don't use any Stack Exchange site).

Comment: Like I said, I can understand per-site metas not being there, but meta.stackoverflow.com is different.  It's not just for discussion about Stack Overflow, it's for discussion about the engine and all sites in general.